# Extend space for many authors in conference paper

Tags: spacing, xetex, packages

### Prologue

For a conference paper, I am asked to use an existing style file. The typesetting code apparently has a history of re-use and adaptations of more than 20 years, and it looks pretty crumbled to me. Still, this seems to be the state of the art for conference papers in our field, and in the past I found it easier so far to use the provided styles, rather than creating something from scratch using the numerous specifications (margins, font sizes, spacing ...). And even though I usually compile the source successfully with XeLaTex (for which it wasn't written), I'm always afraid that this will break things.

### Current Problem

In a paper I'm currently typesetting, there are six authors.
The submission instructions ask for full affiliation address,
which must be typeset in the same size as the author names,
and they explicitely don't want to see footnote affiliations.
This creates a huge author block (I even needed to line-break email addresses),
and it causes a collision with the text body.

[image: collision of affiliations and text body]

### Actual Question

If I choose to adhere to the space-consuming layout instructions,
how can I move the text body further down?
I tried to hack it with `\vspace` (starred and non-starred, inside and outside `\authors{...}`),
but the best I could do was moving the left column further down, but not both.

### MWE

Below is an MWE which produces the above output (the package `tia` is the style file, see further down):

```
% !TEX TS-program=XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt,xetex]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{tia}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Extensive, Two-lined Title\\ With Two Lines of Text}


\author{Author Number 1\\
  Institute of\\ Exampelistics\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author1@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 2\\
  Long-Named Example\\ Institute\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.2}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 3\\
  Department of Long Research\\ and Long-Named Example\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.3}\\\url{@example.com}
  \AND
  Author Number 4\\
  Institute of Example Research\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.4}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 5\\
  Long-Named Example Institute\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.5}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 6\\
  Institute of\\ Exampelistics\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author6@example.com}\\
}

\date{}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[54]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[55-57]

\end{document}
```

And here is the fraction of the style file which I suspect to be responsible for the collision. In the MWE, only this fraction is used (and saved in `tia.sty`):

```
\setlength\topmargin{0.0in} \setlength\oddsidemargin{-0.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in} \setlength\textwidth{6.25in}
\setlength\columnsep{0.2in}
\newlength\titlebox
\setlength\titlebox{2.25in}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}   \setlength\headsep{0pt}
%\setlength\footheight{0pt}
\setlength\footskip{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}      \pagestyle{empty}
\flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy

\flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy

% Title stuff, taken from deproc.
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
   \twocolumn[\@maketitle] \@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
\def\@maketitle{\vbox to \titlebox{\hsize\textwidth
 \linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.125in minus 0.125in \centering
 {\Large\bf \@title \par} \vskip 0.2in plus 1fil minus 0.1in
 {\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rm and}\enspace}%
  \def\And{\end{tabular}\hss \egroup \hskip 1in plus 2fil 
           \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hss\egroup \hfil\hfil\egroup
          \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 0.125in
           \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
             \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}
  \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
    \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\@author 
                            \end{tabular}\hss\egroup
    \hfil\hfil\egroup}
  \vskip 0.3in plus 2fil minus 0.1in
}}
```

Comment: Make the `2.25in` bigger?

Comment: This is even suggested in the comments, as I see now. It works in the MWE, but it has no effect in my actual document. Rats.

Comment: Oops. Missed the second half of your comment or I wouldn't have pointed out it works as an answer. You might take `tia` out of your MWE as it doesn't seem to be standard. (If it turns out to be involved, you can post a link.) Unless it is in MikTeX but not TeX Live....

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. `tia` is just the style file – the second block of code is in a file called `tia.sty`. I'll re-work my MWE to reproduce the error as soon as I have time.

Comment: Ok, I basically outsmarted myself. Changing the length of the titlebox had no effect in my actual document because there was *yet another* `\setlength\titlebox{...}` command further down in the preamble. Well, sometimes a good sleep is all you need to see the problem. – Although my actual problem was a stupid mistake not covered in the question posted, I'll still leave it here, since now there is a matching pair of question and answer that might help somebody else out in the future.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've spent hours trying to find what turns out to be *obvious* after sleep/a walk/a break/food/... ;). Glad you found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increasing the height of the title box, `\titlebox`, works for me. I had to comment out `tia` as I don't have it but, otherwise, it works fine. I tried with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX, with and without `xltxtra`. All fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,xetex]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

% \usepackage{tia}% not part of TeX Live?
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\setlength\topmargin{0.0in} \setlength\oddsidemargin{-0.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in} \setlength\textwidth{6.25in}
\setlength\columnsep{0.2in}
\newlength\titlebox
\setlength\titlebox{3.5in}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}   \setlength\headsep{0pt}
%\setlength\footheight{0pt}
\setlength\footskip{0pt}
\thispagestyle{empty}      \pagestyle{empty}
\flushbottom \twocolumn \sloppy

% Title stuff, taken from deproc.
\def\maketitle{\par
 \begingroup
   \def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
   \def\@makefnmark{\hbox to 0pt{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
   \twocolumn[\@maketitle] \@thanks
 \endgroup
 \setcounter{footnote}{0}
 \let\maketitle\relax \let\@maketitle\relax
 \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax}
\def\@maketitle{\vbox to \titlebox{\hsize\textwidth
 \linewidth\hsize \vskip 0.125in minus 0.125in \centering
 {\Large\bfseries \@title \par} \vskip 0.2in plus 1fil minus 0.1in
 {\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rmfamily and}\enspace}%
  \def\And{\end{tabular}\hss \egroup \hskip 1in plus 2fil
           \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bfseries}%
  \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hss\egroup \hfil\hfil\egroup
          \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 0.125in
           \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
             \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bfseries}
  \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
    \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bfseries\@author
                            \end{tabular}\hss\egroup
    \hfil\hfil\egroup}
  \vskip 0.3in plus 2fil minus 0.1in
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Extensive, Two-lined Title\\ With Two Lines of Text}


\author{Author Number 1\\
  Institute of\\ Exampelistics\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author1@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 2\\
  Long-Named Example\\ Institute\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.2}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 3\\
  Department of Long Research\\ and Long-Named Example\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.3}\\\url{@example.com}
  \AND
  Author Number 4\\
  Institute of Example Research\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.4}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 5\\
  Long-Named Example Institute\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author.number.5}\\\url{@example.com}
  \And
  Author Number 6\\
  Institute of\\ Exampelistics\\
  University of Example\\
  \url{author6@example.com}\\
}

\date{}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[54]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[55-57]

\end{document}
```

[image: deeper box]